# Why does using kable_save to write a pdf table cause html tables of the same name to be deleted?

Tags: r, kable

Using kableExtra::save_kable, I find that saving as a pdf causes a previously saved  html table with the same name to be deleted. In this example:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1:4), b = c(5:8))
df <- kableExtra::kable(df)
kableExtra::save_kable(df, file = "table.html")
kableExtra::save_kable(df, file = "table.pdf")
```

only table.pdf is saved.

However, after swapping the order:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1:4), b = c(5:8))
df <- kableExtra::kable(df)
kableExtra::save_kable(df, file = "table.pdf")
kableExtra::save_kable(df, file = "table.html")
```

both tables are now saved.

This gives me a fix, but I'm wondering if this behavior is by design and whether it can be modified without re-ordering the code, which I may not always want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior cannot be changed without modifying the function. When you give `save_kable` HTML input and ask for PDF output, it writes the HTML file (overwriting anything that already exists), converts it to PDF, and then deletes the HTML file to clean up after itself. [You can see this looking at the code on Github](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/blob/46a42a1d82aad9bacb8c0e17a0e91e9c29104ed3/R/save_kable.R#L61) (`unlink` is the R command for deleting a file).

A few options:

- File a feature request with `kableExtra` and hope they are responsive.
- Modify the code yourself. The `save_kable_latex` function takes an optional argument to keep the intermediate `.tex` file, you could take the same approach here.
- If you frequently want both PDF and HTML, you could write a little wrapper function that calls these two in the correct order, e.g.,

```
# (untested)
save_kable_pdf_html = function(..., file) {
  kableExtra::save_kable(..., file = paste0(file, ".pdf"))
  kableExtra::save_kable(df, file = paste0(file, ".html"))
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. I'll file a feature request and use the workaround.